# Javascript InnerHtml in Firefox

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Anyone know why this isn't working in Firefox?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function goHo() {
hu.innerHTML="????";
}
</script>
<div class="contentPane" id="Calculator" style="display: block;">
                    <h2>Savings Calculator</h2><a href="Home" class="backArrow"></a>
                    <h3>How much do you spend on heating and hot water a year?</h3>
                    <div id="SpendOptions">
                        <ul class="optionList">

                            <a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo()" onMouseOver="hu.innerHTML='£60-180'"><li id="CostOption1">£600 - £900</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo()" onMouseOver="hu.innerHTML='£90-240'"><li id="CostOption2">£900 - £1200</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo()" onMouseOver="hu.innerHTML='£120-300'"><li id="CostOption3">£1200 - £1500</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo()" onMouseOver="hu.innerHTML='£150-360'"><li id="CostOption4">£1500 - £1800</li></a>
                            <a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo()" onMouseOver="hu.innerHTML='£360'"><li id="CostOption5">£1800+</li></a>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
  <div id="SavingsBox" style="display: block;">
                        <h4>This year you could save:</h4>
                        <h1 id="hu"></h1>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you think each ID creates a JavaScript variable? Or is hu defined somewhere else? If not use document.getElementById

Comment: Putting all elements in `window` by their IDs is a IE perversion (which apparently has infected Safari).  Replace it (everywhere) with getElementById or the appropriate jQuery call and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

`hu` should be `document.getElementById("hu")`. (Just because an item has an ID, that does not mean that it will be a declared variable (id and existence as a variable have little to do with each other))

Comment: An element with id="SavingsBox", does not mean that there is a variable called "SavingsBox". A variable called "chicken" noes not mean there is an iid="chicken".

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure that helps fix the problem. This is working in Safari but not Firefox. Essentially when you hover over a selection I want the ID=HU to change the contents

Comment: They mean your function should be: `function goHo() { document.getElementById("hu").innerHTML = "????"; }`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 function goHo() {
     document.getElementById('hu').innerHTML="????";
 }
```

Comment: @user794008 I have tested your code and it is working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
    document.getElementById('hu').innerHTML = "???"

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOut="goHo('????')" onMouseOver="goHo('£60-180')">...

function goHo(html) {
   document.getElementById('hu').innerHTML=html;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8fUcG/2/

Comment: In FF, mouseout doesn't work. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fUcG/2/